# Why $Pr[X-\mu \geq t]= Pr[e^{\lambda(X-\mu)} \geq e^{\lambda t}]$ for all $\lambda> 0$

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, bounds, differential-privacy, randomized-algorithms

I hope everyone is having a nice day. I don't know why this inequality holds.

$$
Pr[X-\mu \geq t]= Pr[e^{\lambda(X-\mu)} \geq e^{\lambda t}]
$$

For $\lambda >0$. I guess it has something to do because the transformation of $e^x$ doesn't affect the inequality, but my question is, if that happens, how I know is the same probability?

I am trying to solve this question because I am learning about differential privacy that uses the Chernoff Bound, which uses this equality. These are the links where they use this equality:

Link:

1. [https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ecprice/courses/randomized/notes/lec2.pdf](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eecprice/courses/randomized/notes/lec2.pdf)
2. https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_3_chernoff_bounds.php
3. [http://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/pr/chernoff.html](http://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/pr/chernoff.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability is equal because the transformations are equivalences. Read your formula with an unknown non-random variable $x$ instead of a random variable $X$ to convince yourself that this holds:

$$ X-\mu\geq t \iff \lambda(X-\mu)\geq \lambda t \iff e^{\lambda(X-\mu)}\geq e^{\lambda t}.$$

(Of course, this requires that $\lambda>0$.)

This is just a consequence of the fact that (1) multiplication by a positive number is monotone and (2) exponentiation is monotone.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Stephan, seems good to me. Have a nice day